# Git Plugin Disabled in Android Studio, Not loaded. The required plugin "Git" is disabled

Tags: android-studio, plugins

[image: Git got disabled in Android Studio, Not able to load Git]

Git got disabled in Android Studio, Not able to load Git.
Not loaded. The required plugin "Git" is disabled

Answer (score 1):

You can manually enable the git:

> File -> Settings -> Plugins -> serch git -> Enable Git Integration ->
> OK -> restart Android Studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWoaW.png).